# UNPIVOT SQL with columns query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table `Price`:

```
WhseKey ItemKey CurrID  Sheet1Price  Sheet2Price Sheet3Price   Sheet4Price
24      452     USD     14.90000     14.90000   13.70000       12.50000    11.03000
24      453     USD     1.15000      1.15000    1.05000        0.95000     0.85000
24      454     USD     12.95000     12.95000   11.90000       10.88000    9.70000  
24      459     USD     3.95000      3.95000    3.65000        3.30000     2.92000
```

I want the result to be like:

```
CurrID Name ID 
USD Sheet1Price Sheet1Price
USD Sheet2Price Sheet2Price
USD Sheet3Price Sheet3Price
USD Sheet4Price Sheet4Price
```

Current query:

```
select UPV.CurrID , UPV.Name
from Price
unpivot
(
    Name
    for Price in (Sheet1Price, Sheet2Price, Sheet3Price, Sheet4Price)
) UPV;
```

But the result is not correct, it comes as:

```
CurrID Name
USD 14.90000
USD 13.70000
USD 12.50000
USD 11.03000
USD 1.15000
USD 1.05000
USD 0.95000
USD 0.85000
USD 12.95000
USD 11.90000
```

What i am missing?

Comment: Are you asking for the output to include the field names, rather than their values?  Why are you outputting `Sheet*N*Price ' twice on each row?

Answer (score 0):

To output filed names you should use `UPV.Price`, Try this:

```
select WhseKey, ItemKey, UPV.CurrID , UPV.Name, UPV.Price
from Price
unpivot
(
    Price
    for Name in (Sheet1Price, Sheet2Price, Sheet3Price, Sheet4Price)
) UPV;
```